# Redirect to another page button inside option tag always redirect to the same page (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

I made a `<select>` tag with  some `option` tags in it

```
<select name="Persons" onchange="changePage(this.value); this.selectedindex = -1">
<option class="op" value="0">option1 </option>
<option class="op" value="1">option2 </option>
```

and so on..
and using js I made an array of values `values = ['0','1']`

then made a function to redirect to a page according to the value clicked

```
function changePage(){
   for (let i=0; i < values.length ; i++){
    let value = values[i]
        if (value=1){
            window.location.replace("link1");
           } else if (value=2) {
            window.location.replace("link2");
           }
    }
}
}
```

whenever I click option 1 or 2 it redirect to option 1 only

expected : redirect according to `value` (if =1 redirect to link1 if =2 redirect to link2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there is logic gap between what you want and what you have written.
You are iterating the `value` array where second iteration will give `value=1` and the `if(value=1)` statement will be always be true. That's why you are being redirected to `link1` always.
Changes:

No need to maintain the JS array `value`. Change the function as below:

```
function changePage(optionVal){

 if (optionVal == "1"){
            window.location.replace("link1");
         } else if (optionVal == "2") {
            window.location.replace("link2");
        }
}
```

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it works for you! :)